# Get structure data of content from an URL

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, ruby

I got the structure of content from [3. Data model — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)
Manually as following:

```
{'None'},
{'NotImplemeted'},
{'Ellipsis'},
{'numbers.Number':
    {'Integral':{'int','bool'}},
    {    'Real':'float'},
    { 'Complex':'complex'}
    },
{'Sequences':
    {'Immutable sequences':['Strings', 'Tuples', 'Bytes'],
       'Mutable sequences':['List', 'Byte Arrays'],
    },
{'Set types':
    {'Sets', 'Frozen sets'}
    },
{'Mappings':
    {'Dictionary'}
    },
{'Callable types':
    {'User-defined functions':{'Special attributes'}},
    {'Instance methods'},
    {'Generator functions'},
    {'Coroutine functions'},
    {'Asynchrous generator functions'},
    {'Built-in Functions'},
    {'Built-in Methods'},
    {'Classes'},
    {'Class Instances'},
    },
{'Modules'},
{'Custom class'},
{'Class instances'},
{'File objects'},
{'Internal Types':
    {'Code objects', 'Frame objects', 'Traceback objects', 'Slice objects',
    'Static method objects', 'Class method objects'},
    },
```

How to retrieve such a data structure from the URL in a professional way ?

Comment: Show us the amateur way.

Comment: Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V @ElisByberi

Comment: Hahaha, you made my day!

Comment: Python documentation is hand written in .rst format and it is open sourced. Then html is generated out of these files. It should be much easier - if you are planning to do this automatically - to parse these files instead of going through htmls directly. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/3.6/Doc/reference/datamodel.rst But still remember that it was hand written, could contain bugs and is only as reliable as people who wrote it.